# Using Apps Script, how can I display a google doc checklist from information in a google sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs, google-docs-api

I am generating a google doc from a google sheet. The sheet contains a list of weeks down the side and along the top each column is an activity header. The body of the spreadsheet is the number of hours spent on each activity in a given week.
The information outputs to a Google Doc like this (ignore the bullet points) -

- Week starting Mon Aug 21 2023
- □ Admin: 0.5 hour
- □ Forward Planning: 1 hour
- □ Reporting - Assessments: 0.5 hour
- □ Tracking Pupil Progress meetings - SFL/HT: 0.5 hour
- 
- Week starting Mon Aug 28 2023
- □ Admin: 0.5 hour
- □ Forward Planning: 1 hour
- □ Reporting - Assessments: 0.5 hour
- □ Staff Meeting - SIP: 1 hour
- □ Staff Meeting - Open Evening: 1 hour

The squares are generated like this

```
    // Loop through the activity headings
for (var column = startColumn; column <= sheet.getLastColumn(); column++) {
  var activityHeading = sheet.getRange(4, column).getValue(); // Get the activity heading
  var cellValue = sheet.getRange(week, column).getValue(); // Get the cell value

  // Check if the cell is not blank and not text
  if (cellValue !== "" && typeof cellValue === "number") {
    var hours = cellValue;
    var formattedHours = hours <= 1 ? hours + " hour" : hours + " hours";
    activities.push("\u25A1 " + activityHeading + ": " + formattedHours);
  } else if (typeof cellValue === "string" && cellValue.trim() !== "") {
    activities.push("\u25A1 " + activityHeading + ": " + cellValue);
  }
}

// Print the activities for the week
if (activities.length > 0) {
  body.appendParagraph(formattedWeekDate).setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING2);
  activities.forEach(function (activity) {
    body.appendParagraph(activity);
  });
  body.appendParagraph(""); // Add an empty line between weeks
}
```

How do I replace the text symbols with the dynamic checklist functionality that exists in Google Docs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to change `\u25A1` to a checkbox in Google Documents.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

#### Issue and workaround:

In the current stage, when the Google Document service (DocumentApp) is used, it seems that the checkbox cannot be used as the paragraph bullet. But, fortunately, when Google Docs API is used, this can be achieved. Recently, it seems that this can be achieved.

In this answer, I would like to achieve your goal using Google Docs API. When your showing script is modified, it becomes as follows.

Unfortunately, in your showing script, the following variables are not declared.

- `sheet`, `startColumn`, `week`, `activities`, `body`, `formattedWeekDate`

In this modification, it supposes that the above variables are declared elsewhere in your script. Please be careful about this.

#### Modified script:

This modified script uses Google Docs API. So, [please enable Google Docs API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services).

```js
// Loop through the activity headings
for (var column = startColumn; column <= sheet.getLastColumn(); column++) {
  var activityHeading = sheet.getRange(4, column).getValue(); // Get the activity heading
  var cellValue = sheet.getRange(week, column).getValue(); // Get the cell value

  // Check if the cell is not blank and not text
  if (cellValue !== "" && typeof cellValue === "number") {
    var hours = cellValue;
    var formattedHours = hours <= 1 ? hours + " hour" : hours + " hours";
    activities.push(activityHeading + ": " + formattedHours);
  } else if (typeof cellValue === "string" && cellValue.trim() !== "") {
    activities.push(activityHeading + ": " + cellValue);
  }
}

// Print the activities for the week
if (activities.length > 0) {
  body.appendParagraph(formattedWeekDate).setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING2);
  var idx = activities.map(activity => body.getChildIndex(body.appendParagraph(activity)));
  body.appendParagraph(""); // Add an empty line between weeks
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument(); // or DocumentApp.openById("documentId")
  doc.saveAndClose();
  var documentId = doc.getId();
  const content = Docs.Documents.get(documentId).body.content;
  const requests = idx.map(id => ({
    createParagraphBullets: {
      bulletPreset: "BULLET_CHECKBOX",
      range: { startIndex: content[id + 1].startIndex, endIndex: content[id + 1].endIndex }
    }
  }));
  Docs.Documents.batchUpdate({ requests }, documentId);
}
```

- Unfortunately, I cannot know the origin of `body` in your script. So, in this modification, I used `DocumentApp.getActiveDocument()`. If you are using `DocumentApp.openById("documentId")`. Please modify to it. If you have used `doc` elsewhere in your script, you can remove the line of `var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();`.

#### Testing:

When sample values are used in Google Spreadsheet, the above-modified script obtains the following result. As a test, I checked the checkbox of the last line. You can see the checkboxes created by Google Docs API.

[image]

#### Note:

- I tested my modified script using a simple sample Spreadsheet. When you test this script, when an error occurs, please provide the script reflecting my proposed modified script and your Spreadsheet. By this, I would like to confirm it.

#### References:

- [Method: documents.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/batchUpdate)
- [CreateParagraphBulletsRequest](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/request#createparagraphbulletsrequest)

### Added:

When I saw your provided Spreadsheet including your current script, I noticed that unfortunately, you are not correctly using my proposed modification. I think that this is the reason for your current issue. Your current script for occuring the following issue is as follows.

> I have checked the listed variables are declared and added the Google Docs API service. I moved the line code doc.saveAndClose(); code outside the loop and added some activity validation. I am left with this error - GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to docs.documents.batchUpdate failed with error: Must specify at least one request. printWeeklyActivitiesToFolder @ Docs.Documents.batchUpdate({ requests }, documentId);

#### Your current script

```js
function printWeeklyActivitiesToFolder() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var setupSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('setup');
  var folderId = setupSheet.getRange('D4').getValue();
  var targetFolder;

  // Check if the folder ID is provided in D4
  if (folderId !== "") {
    targetFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  } else {
    // Use the default top-level folder if D4 is blank
    targetFolder = DriveApp.getRootFolder();
  }

  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('WTA');
  var startRow = 6; // Starting row for the week dates
  var startColumn = 3; // Starting column for the activity headings

  // Retrieve the document name from setup tab cell D2
  var documentName = setupSheet.getRange('D2').getValue();
  // Retrieve the document title from setup tab cell D3
  var documentTitle = setupSheet.getRange('D3').getValue();

  // Create a new Google Doc with the provided name
  var doc = DocumentApp.create(documentName);

  // Get or create the header section
  var headerSection = doc.getHeader();
  if (!headerSection) {
    headerSection = doc.addHeader();
  }

  var headerParagraph = headerSection.appendParagraph(documentTitle);
  headerParagraph.setAlignment(DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);

  var body = doc.getBody();
var hasValidActivities = false; // Flag to track if there are valid activities

// Loop through each week
for (var week = startRow; week <= sheet.getLastRow(); week++) {
    var weekDate = sheet.getRange(week, 1).getValue(); // Get the week date from column A
    var formattedWeekDate = "Week starting " + formatDate(weekDate);

    var activities = [];

    // Loop through the activity headings
    for (var column = startColumn; column <= sheet.getLastColumn(); column++) {
      var activityHeading = sheet.getRange(4, column).getValue(); // Get the activity heading
      var cellValue = sheet.getRange(week, column).getValue(); // Get the cell value

      // Check if the cell is not blank and not text
      if (cellValue !== "" && typeof cellValue === "number") {
        var hours = cellValue;
        var formattedHours = hours <= 1 ? hours + " hour" : hours + " hours";
        activities.push(activityHeading + ": " + formattedHours);
      hasValidActivities = true; // Set the flag to true if there is at least one valid activity
      } else if (typeof cellValue === "string" && cellValue.trim() !== "") {
        activities.push(activityHeading + ": " + cellValue);
      hasValidActivities = true; // Set the flag to true if there is at least one valid activity
      }
    }

    // Print the activities for the week
if (activities.length > 0 && hasValidActivities) {
      body.appendParagraph(formattedWeekDate).setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING2);
      var idx = activities.map(activity => body.getChildIndex(body.appendParagraph(activity)));
      body.appendParagraph(""); // Add an empty line between weeks
      var documentId = doc.getId();
      const content = Docs.Documents.get(documentId).body.content;
      const requests = idx.map(id => {
        var startIndex = content[id + 1] ? content[id + 1].startIndex : null;
        var endIndex = content[id + 1] ? content[id + 1].endIndex : null;
        if (startIndex !== null && endIndex !== null) {
          return {
            createParagraphBullets: {
              bulletPreset: "BULLET_CHECKBOX",
              range: { startIndex: startIndex, endIndex: endIndex }
            }
          };
        }
        return null; // Skip the request if the range is invalid
      }).filter(request => request !== null); // Remove null requests
      Docs.Documents.batchUpdate({ requests }, documentId);
    }
  }

  // Save and close the Google Doc
  doc.saveAndClose();

  // Move the document to the target folder
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(doc.getId());
  file.moveTo(targetFolder);

  // Get the URL of the created document
  var docUrl = doc.getUrl();

  // Create the link using the folder ID
  var link = 'https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/' + folderId;

  // Set the link in cell D5 of the 'setup' tab
  setupSheet.getRange('D5').setValue(link);

  // Set the document URL in cell D6 of the 'setup' tab
  setupSheet.getRange('D6').setValue(docUrl);

  Logger.log("Weekly activities have been printed to the document: " + docUrl);

  return [spreadsheet.getId(), spreadsheet.getName(), folderId];
}

function formatDate(date) {
  var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(date), "GMT+0100", "E MMM dd yyyy");
  return formattedDate;
}
```

#### Modified script of your current script:

When your above script is modified, it becomes as follows.

```js
function printWeeklyActivitiesToFolder() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var setupSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('setup');
  var folderId = setupSheet.getRange('D4').getValue();
  var targetFolder;

  // Check if the folder ID is provided in D4
  if (folderId !== "") {
    targetFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  } else {
    // Use the default top-level folder if D4 is blank
    targetFolder = DriveApp.getRootFolder();
  }

  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('WTA');
  var startRow = 6; // Starting row for the week dates
  var startColumn = 3; // Starting column for the activity headings

  // Retrieve the document name from setup tab cell D2
  var documentName = setupSheet.getRange('D2').getValue();
  // Retrieve the document title from setup tab cell D3
  var documentTitle = setupSheet.getRange('D3').getValue();

  // Create a new Google Doc with the provided name
  var doc = DocumentApp.create(documentName);
  var documentId = doc.getId();

  // Get or create the header section
  var headerSection = doc.getHeader();
  if (!headerSection) {
    headerSection = doc.addHeader();
  }

  var headerParagraph = headerSection.appendParagraph(documentTitle);
  headerParagraph.setAlignment(DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);

  var body = doc.getBody();
  var hasValidActivities = false; // Flag to track if there are valid activities

  console.log(sheet.getLastRow())

  // Loop through each week
  for (var week = startRow; week <= sheet.getLastRow(); week++) {
    var weekDate = sheet.getRange(week, 1).getValue(); // Get the week date from column A
    var formattedWeekDate = "Week starting " + formatDate(weekDate);

    var activities = [];

    // Loop through the activity headings
    for (var column = startColumn; column <= sheet.getLastColumn(); column++) {
      var activityHeading = sheet.getRange(4, column).getValue(); // Get the activity heading
      var cellValue = sheet.getRange(week, column).getValue(); // Get the cell value

      // Check if the cell is not blank and not text
      if (cellValue !== "" && typeof cellValue === "number") {
        var hours = cellValue;
        var formattedHours = hours <= 1 ? hours + " hour" : hours + " hours";
        activities.push(activityHeading + ": " + formattedHours);
        hasValidActivities = true; // Set the flag to true if there is at least one valid activity
      } else if (typeof cellValue === "string" && cellValue.trim() !== "") {
        activities.push(activityHeading + ": " + cellValue);
        hasValidActivities = true; // Set the flag to true if there is at least one valid activity
      }
    }

    // Print the activities for the week
    if (activities.length > 0 && hasValidActivities) {
      body.appendParagraph(formattedWeekDate).setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING2);
      var idx = activities.map(activity => body.getChildIndex(body.appendParagraph(activity)));
      body.appendParagraph(""); // Add an empty line between weeks
      doc.saveAndClose();
      const content = Docs.Documents.get(documentId).body.content;
      const requests = idx.map(id => ({
        createParagraphBullets: {
          bulletPreset: "BULLET_CHECKBOX",
          range: { startIndex: content[id + 1].startIndex, endIndex: content[id + 1].endIndex }
        }
      }));
      Docs.Documents.batchUpdate({ requests }, documentId);
      doc = DocumentApp.openById(documentId);
      body = doc.getBody();
    }
  }

  // Save and close the Google Doc
  // doc.saveAndClose();

  // Move the document to the target folder
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(doc.getId());
  file.moveTo(targetFolder);

  // Get the URL of the created document
  var docUrl = doc.getUrl();

  // Create the link using the folder ID
  var link = 'https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/' + folderId;

  // Set the link in cell D5 of the 'setup' tab
  setupSheet.getRange('D5').setValue(link);

  // Set the document URL in cell D6 of the 'setup' tab
  setupSheet.getRange('D6').setValue(docUrl);

  Logger.log("Weekly activities have been printed to the document: " + docUrl);

  return [spreadsheet.getId(), spreadsheet.getName(), folderId];
}

function formatDate(date) {
  var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(date), "GMT+0100", "E MMM dd yyyy");
  return formattedDate;
}
```

Comment: I have checked the listed variables are declared and added the Google Docs API service. I moved the line `code`  doc.saveAndClose(); `code` outside the loop and added some activity validation. I am left with this error - GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to docs.documents.batchUpdate failed with error: Must specify at least one request.
printWeeklyActivitiesToFolder @ Docs.Documents.batchUpdate({ requests }, documentId); - spreadsheet and code - [LINK] (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KEYttngVc2lgK4RqQGgsKs6XVbeU_36kulRKA01dxEk/copy)

Comment: @grantc Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. When I saw your provided Spreadsheet including your current script, I thought that I apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, you are not correctly using my proposed modification. I think that this is the reason for your current issue. From your provided Spreadsheet including your current script, I added the modified sript of your current script. Please confirm it.

Comment: @grantc By the way, I think that your actual script is complicated. So, I simply reflected my proposed script for your showing script in your current script. Please be careful about this. But, when I tested the modified script with your provided Spreadsheet, I confirmed no error.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. Your modified script works with no errors.